# Restoring wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress, backup

I had a wordpress website installed on a remote hosting server in a dedicated folder. The folder was mistakenly deleted from the server.

I have a backup file done incorrectly - meaning, only by a whole download of the files in the dedicated wordpress folder, without the data from the database.

Now, the database is still existing on the server, with no change. I assumed that uploading the files back to where they were will fix the problem but I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/wordpress/wp-includes/pluggable-deprecated.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/wordpress/wp-settings.php on line 202
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: This kind of problem will probably require to call a specialist who can be physically here :-/

Comment: I'm not sure I follow...

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend downloading a copy of the standard WordPress files from the WordPress archive that is the same version of WordPress that your backup is using:

http://wordpress.org/download/release-archive/

Copy the files from the zip onto into a new folder.

Next copy everything inside of the /wp-content/ directory from your backup into the /wp-content/ inside the newly created folder. The wp-content directory should contain all the modified and uploaded files from your previous WordPress install.

Then copy the wp-config.php from the / directory of your backup into the / directory of the new folder overwriting the file in the new folder. The wp-config.php contains all your information for connecting to your database, double check to make sure this is all correct.

Upload this new folder to the same place the old files were on your web server.

Hopefully these steps get you a little closer to getting your site back up and running!